# Is there a way to chroot into 32bit system from 64bit host?

Tags: chroot, 64bit, 32bit

I have a 64bit Debian system running on my laptop. I wanted to chroot into a RasPiOS system (Raspberry Pi OS), but this OS is only 32 bit. When I try to chroot I get the following error:

```
# chroot /media/rpi /bin/bash
chroot: failed to run command ‘/bin/bash’: Exec format error

# ls -al /media/rpi/bin/bash
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 925124 2019-04-18 06:12:36 /media/rpi/bin/bash*
```

Some people say it's because of the mismatch between 64 and 32 bit arch.

So is there a way to chroot into 32bit system from 64bit host?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difficulty comes from the fact that your Raspberry Pi OS environment is built for ARM CPUs, not the x86 CPU used in your laptop.

To be able to `chroot` into it, you need to install an emulator so that the binaries can run on your laptop:

```
sudo apt install qemu-user-static
```